# How to get the index of rows that have lower frequent values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can I get the index of rows that have less count values. For example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'price' : [1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 2]})
out[1]:
    price
0   1
1   2
2   1
3   3
4   5
5   2
6   2
```

How can I get the index of price = 1, 3 ,5, which only occurs less than 3 times in the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `duplicated`

```
test[~test.price.duplicated(keep=False)]
   price
3      3
4      5
```

---

```
test.index[~test.price.duplicated(keep=False)]
Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Update then you need `transform`

```
test[test.groupby('price').price.transform('count')<=1]
   price
3      3
4      5

test[test.groupby('price').price.transform('count')<3].index
Int64Index([0, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Hi, W-B, I have updated my question. What I need is to get the index of values which occur less than some number, not just those occur only one time.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the items with `value_counts` and choose those that are "rare enough":

```
THRESHOLD = 3
is_rare = test['price'].value_counts() < THRESHOLD
rare = is_rare[is_rare].index
#Int64Index([1, 5, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Next, find the rows that contain the rare items:

```
are_rare_rows = test["price"].isin(rare)
are_rare_rows[are_rare_rows].index
#Int64Index([0, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Hi DYZ, thank you for you answer, but I need [0, 2, 3, 4]